# Fourth degree polynomial in trajectory problem

Tags: polynomials

I have a problem where I'm trying to find the distance needed to lead a moving target with a projectile given variable parameters. I've had limited success so far and I think I may be close to a solution but I'm not sure how to go about the final steps involving a fourth degree polynomial. I've looked into Ferrari's method and tried using Cardano's formula as well as Lagrange's resolvents but I haven't been able to come to grips with them in terms of finding the real roots. Before showing the equation I'd also like to show the method of obtaining it in case I made an error in getting to where I am in the first place. This is a diagram of the problem:

[image]

The target is moving with velocity $v_1$ and the cannon firing the projectile is initially at an angle $a_1$ and distance $d_1$ from the target. The projectile is fired at velocity $v_2$ and angle $a_2$ over a distance $d_2$ where it meets the target after a distance of $x$. The unknowns are $a_2$, $d_2$, and $x$.

The relevant equations used are $$d_2 = \frac{v_2^2sin(2a_2)}{g}$$ $$t = \frac{d_2}{v_2cos(a_2)}$$$$x = v_1t$$
from which two equations in terms of $a_2$ are derived:
$$\frac{x}{v_1} = \frac{d_2}{v_2cos(a_2)}$$
$$\frac{x}{v_1} = \frac{2\,v_2^2\,sin(a_2)cos(a_2)}{g\,v_2\,cos(a_2)}$$
$$a_2 = arcsin\left(\frac{x\,g}{2\,v_1\,v_2}\right)$$
and then with the law of cosines:
$$d_2^2 = x^2 + d_1^2 - 2\,x\,d_1cos(a_1)$$
$$\frac{v_2^2sin(2a_2)}{g} = \sqrt{x^2 + d_1^2 - 2\,x\,d_1cos(a_1)}$$
$$a_2 = \frac12arcsin\left(\frac{g}{v_2^2}\sqrt{x^2 + d_1^2 - 2\,x\,d_1cos(a_1)}\right)$$
and finally setting these two equal to solve for x:
$$arcsin\left(\frac{x\,g}{2\,v_1\,v_2}\right) = \frac12arcsin\left(\frac{g}{v_2^2}\sqrt{x^2 + d_1^2 - 2\,x\,d_1cos(a_1)}\right)$$
$$2\left(\frac{x\,g}{2\,v_1\,v_2}\right)\sqrt{1-\left(\frac{x\,g}{2\,v_1\,v_2}\right)^2} = \frac{g}{v_2^2}\sqrt{x^2 + d_1^2 - 2\,x\,d_1cos(a_1)}$$$$\frac{x^2}{v_1^2}\left(1 - \frac{x^2\,g^2}{4\,v_1^2\,v_2^2}\right) = \frac{1}{v_2^2}(x^2 + d_1^2 - 2\,x\,d_1cos(a_1))$$$$\frac{x^2\,v_2^2}{v_1^2} - \frac{x^4\,g^2}{4\,v_1^4} = x^2 + d_1^2 - 2\,x\,d_1cos(a_1)$$$$\left(\frac{g^2}{4\,v_1^4}\right)\,x^4 + \left(1-\frac{v_2^2}{v_1^2}\right)\,x^2 + \left(-2\,d_1\,cos(a_1)\right)\,x + (d_1^2) = 0$$
and this is where I get stuck. I can recognize the fourth degree polynomial but I don't know how to go about getting the real roots. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Was the diagram given or did you draw it?

Comment: Can you specify the horizontal direction ?

Comment: I drew the diagram. I'm not quite sure what you mean by the horizontal direction but in this case x is meant to represent a variable for distance, sorry for the confusion. The velocity vector v1 lies on the euclidean x-z plane with a y element of 0 and v2 is in x-y-z space (with y being 'up'). Both the target and cannon are at points on the x-z plane as well.

Comment: By horizontal I mean a direction perpendicular to the force of gravity. Isn't v2 in the x-z plane ? Where is d2 ? Where is g ?

Comment: Gravity (g) is in the y-axis and v2 is the velocity of the projectile so it has an x-z component in the direction of d2 and a y component that determines the angle of the projectile's launch, a2. d2 is the distance traveled by the projectile on the x-z plane so it's y component is 0.

Comment: You cannot solve symbolically that equation. Assign values to the data and apply a numerical method.

Comment: So there is no method of solving a fourth degree polynomial in the form of ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e = 0?

Comment: If you cannot factor the polynomial (and this is the case), the method is numerical and/or graphical. A symbolical solution is preferable because permits qualitative estimates but Italian formulae are so complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find the equation for the solution of a depressed fourth degree polynomial on WolframAlpha and it yielded the expected results:

Let $$a = \frac{g^2}{4\,v_1^4}$$ $$c = 1-\frac{v_2^2}{v_1^2}$$ $$d = -2\,d_1\,cos(a_1)$$ $$e = d_1^2$$

$$y = \sqrt[3]{\sqrt{(-72\,e\,a\,c + 27\,a\,d^2 + 2\,c^3)^2 - 4(12\,e\,a + c^2)^3} - 72\,e\,a\,c + 27\,a\,d^2 + 2\,c^3}$$

Then the first root and the one that is real when the parameters are valid:

$$x = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{y}{3\sqrt[3]{2}\,a} + \frac{\sqrt[3]{2}\,(12\,e\,a + c^2)}{3\,a\,y} - \frac{2\,c}{3\,a}} - \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{-1}{3\sqrt[3]{2}\,a}\,y - \frac{\sqrt[3]{2}\,(12\,e\,a + c^2)}{3\,a\,y} - \frac{2\,d}{a\,\sqrt{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{2}\,a}\,y + \frac{\sqrt[3]{2}\,(12\,e\,a + c^2)}{3\,a\,y} - \frac{2\,c}{3\,a}}} - \frac{4\,c}{3\,a}}$$